# Change the pop image in magiczoomplus

Tags: javascript, magiczoomplus

I have requirement  as  follows:

I am using magiczoomplus script. I want to change the pop up image that shows the zoomed image using ajax on run time. Right now I am able to change the main image but zoomed image I am not able to change.

Please suggest how to do it.

Thanks,

Answer (score 2):

after loading the new image call the following api function in javascrip
t.
MagicZoomPlus.refresh()

Comment: This is the correct answer.  Thank you very much.  Needs marked as answered.